# Failed to compile when implementing npm odbc into Next.js project

Tags: node.js, next.js, odbc

I have an SQL Anywhere ODBC local to the this computer and am on a Windows 10 machine using Node v18.18.0 starting a fresh Next v13.5.2 project (blank) then installing odbc 2.4.8, my project starts fine as seen below.

[Project up and running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRXAo.png)

However, in my page.tsx, when I simply start with
`const odbc = require('odbc')`
I get the following errors on my project.

[Project not compiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm2CG.png)

Do you think this is a version issue?

Thank you

I have checked all the supported versions on https://github.com/markdirish/node-odbc